# Getting c++ values from awk output

Tags: c++, awk

```
system("awk 'BEGIN {i=0;}$0 ~/^D/ { i++; printf "i";}END {}' out.txt");
```

I have used this line in my c++ code to count some lines in out.txt. it printing  correct i value.  now i need to use this  **i** count value in c++. can any one help me to do this.

Comment: Please don't do this. This is crazy talk. There are much faster and fairly simple ways of doing this with c++ code instead of invoking another external interpreter

Comment: I suppose You would print `i` value in the END section not every time You found a match... I also assume that the `"` around `i` is not correct. Otherwise You will have a lot if 'i's instead of a number. Anyway `grep -c "^D"` does the same for less price. But I suggest You to consider `Salgar`'s comment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `popen`, instead of `system`.

see here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/popen.html

It's like a cross between fopen() and system(), it "returns" the output of the system call as a unix-style pipe, which is much like a FILE*.

Answer (score 0):

I think a part of me just died inside. The following c++ code will count the number of lines for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>


int line_count(const char * fname)
{
  std::ifstream input(fname); 
  int count=0; 
  if(input.is_open()){
    std::string linebuf; 

    while(1){
      std::getline(input, linebuf); 
      if(input.eof()){
    break;
      }
      count++;
    }
  }else{
    return -1; 
  }

  return count; 
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  int total=0; 
  for(int i=1; i!=argc; i++){
    int rv=line_count(argv[i]);
    if(rv<0){
      std::cerr<<"unable to open file: "<<argv[i]<<std::endl;
    }else{
      std::cout<<"file "<<argv[i]<<" contains "<<rv<<" lines"<<std::endl;
      total+=rv; 
    }
  }
  std::cout<<"Total number of lines = "<<total<<std::endl;

  return 0; 
}
```

(note that there is no test4 file, it's just to show the error reporting)

```
[wc-l $] ./count_lines test1 test2 test3 test4
file test1 contains 8 lines
file test2 contains 13 lines
file test3 contains 16 lines
unable to open file: test4
Total number of lines = 37
[wc-l $]
```

this is the same as the wc -l output:

```
[wc-l $] wc -l test1 test2 test3 test4
 8 test1
13 test2
16 test3
wc: test4: No such file or directory
37 total
[wc-l $]
```